# NSLayoutConstraints Margin y vista que no se muestra

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

¿Que está mal de este código?¿Porque la vista azul no se muestra?

```
let myRedView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
myRedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
myRedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

let myBlueView = UIView()
myBlueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
myBlueView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

myRedView.addSubview(myBlueView)


let blueY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myBlueView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: myRedView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10)
let blueX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myBlueView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: myRedView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10)
//let blueWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myBlueView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200)
//let blueHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myBlueView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200)

myRedView.addConstraints([blueX,blueY])
```

Con o sin el width y el height, no se muestra y no entiendo la razón.

Otra duda que tengo sobre estos constraints es a quien debo aplicarle el `.LeftMargin`. Si a la vista principal sobre la que estoy modelando o a la segunda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si utilizas el `frame` normal no debes poner a `false` la propiedad `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`. Por tanto, debes eliminar la siguiente línea:

```
myRedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Probado en un `Playground` y funciona perfectamente.